# EF code-first how to retrieve navigation-property with Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Following is a data model wherein Entity `A` has a navigation-property `B`

```
[Serializable]
public class X
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }             
}

[Serializable]
public class A : X
{     
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class B : X
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to access table A from database as follows :

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> SelectAsync<T>() where T : X
{
    using (MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext ())
    {
        var dataTable = db.Set<T>();
        var temp = await dataTable.ToListAsync();

        return temp;
    }
}
```

This almost works except that for each instance of `A` returned in the collection `temp` the value of `B` is `null`. Since each `A` has a non `null` `B` in the database I'm surprised with the result of `db.Set<T>()`

**Questions** :

- Why am I getting this result?
- What do I need to do for `db.Set<T>()` to return `A`s with valid   (non-null) `B`s?

---

**Update** 
Based on suggestion of @Camilo Terevinto I tried the following, without luck

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are explicitly disposing the context and you disabled lazy loading, you need to eagerly load the relation:

```
await dataTable.Include("B").ToListAsync();
```

You will need to decide how you determine whether the current `T` contains a navigational `B` though.

Comment: Re:lazy loading please see the update to the question

Comment: I don't know beforehand what navigation property a T would contain. That's why I need a generic solution.

Comment: The only real solution is to pass through parameters the data you want to include. Only enabling lazy loading isn't enough due to the disposal

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it does work though not generic.

Comment: @NGambit Unfortunately, an actual generic solution is pretty hard, as it would involve a lot of reflection that determines which properties are navigational and load them. This would probably be very slow and you should be better off passing the data to include via parameters

Answer (score -1):

I could not say why you get `null` value. Normally, here is how `one-to-one` are configured in Entity Framework.

When runing the following code with your `SelectAsync` method, I get `B` for every value of `A`.

```
public partial class X
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public partial class A
{
    public A()
    {
        B = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual X X { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}

public partial class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AId { get; set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual X X { get; set; }
}
```

### DbContext

```
public partial class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    public virtual DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<B> B { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<X> X { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.A)
            .WithRequired(e => e.X);

        modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.B)
            .WithRequired(e => e.X);
    }
}
```